# Which class diagram is correct: with or without inheritance?

Tags: uml, papyrus

This customer needs to have one payment account.
I'm not sure whether it works to have customer having one inherited class. These are my two ideas:

Without Inheritance:

[image: With Inheritance]

With Inheritance:

[image: Without Inheritance]

Comment: First of all, I guess that you inversed the images... With Inheritance seems more clear even if PaymentAccount could be abstract.

Comment: Both are clear, but having the superclass know how to pull money seems better than having the Customer (and possibly other classes) know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the model without inheritance, a customer could have both a bank account and a credit card. You could add an --{xor}-- constraint between the associations if a customer can only have either one.

The diagram with inheritance clearly shows that a customer cannot have both a bank account and a credit card. But it also demands that each customer has an account. If there are customers without any account, then you should replace multiplicity "1" by "0..1".